How to extract the expression of a combination of Wavefuncion objects in Sympy
The Sympy documentation says that the attribute expr extracts the expression of a Wavefunction object. However, that doesn't seem to work when dealing with linear combinations of wavefunctions.
Consider this example:
import sympy as sp
from sympy.physics.quantum.state import Wavefunction

R = sp.Function('R')
Z = sp.Function('Z')
x,y = sp.symbols('x y', real=True)

ϕ = Wavefunction(R(x)*Z(y), x, y)

(ϕ + ϕ).expr

The expected behavior would be for it to return the expression inside of ϕ times 2. However, it returns an error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[316], line 7
      3 x,y = sp.symbols('x y', real=True)
      5 ϕ = Wavefunction(R(x)*Z(y), x, y)
----> 7 (ϕ + ϕ).expr

AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'expr'

So, what is the right approach to extract the resulting expression out of a linear combination of Wavefunction objects?

Apparently, this can make the conversion that I wanted:
def search_wave_term(Expr):
    new_expr = Expr
    for arg in Expr.args:
        if arg.func == Wavefunction:
            new_expr = new_expr.subs(arg, arg.expr)
        else:
            new_term = search_wave_term(arg)
            new_expr = new_expr.subs(arg, new_term)
    return new_expr

